# replace this.tagName

Tags: javascript

Есть возможность при клике на DIV вернуть его как TEXTAREA типа аля

```
this.tagName.replace(this.tagName, "textarea");
```

Comment: jQuery может делать так:

    $('#myDiv').replaceWith('<textarea id="myDiv">'+$('#myDiv').html()+'</textarea>');

Comment: @Sh4dow, JS тоже :D

Comment: @exec я в курсе) Не люблю велосипеды в продакшене)

Comment: @Sh4dow, нафига `.html()`? А ещё есть вариант, что там встретится `</textarea>` и этому коду крышка. Надо так: `$div.replaceWith($('<textarea>).val($div.text()))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Насколько я знаю `tagName` - read only свойство, соответственно - нет, нельзя.

Comment: Печально... Теперь не буду париться)

Comment: Философия такого поведения на наглядном примере псевдокода:

    cat = new Cat();   // создаем div
    cat.class = 'Cat'; // устанавливаем "тэг"

    // если изменить какой-либо атрибут и, например
    // сказать коту - ты собака, ничего не сделав для того
    // что-бы он ей стал - естественно он останется котом
    cat.class = 'Dog';

Ну а работает именно так потому, что tagName - это, на уровне нативной реализации - геттер, сеттера попросту не существует.

PS: правда под новые браузеры заявленный вами функционал можно реализовать, если интересно напишу без проблем.

Comment: @AlexWindHope спасибо, но в принципе проблема решилась другим подходом.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
<div id="parent">
<div id="child">
</div>
</div>
<script>
var textarea=document.createElement("textarea");
parent.replaceChild(texarea,child);
</script>
```

Comment: Ну код можно дороботать но суть такая!

Comment: Суть была лиш в замене одного tagName на другой! `<div>Some Text</div> должен был стать <textarea>Some Text</textarea>` При продолжительном трахе мозга стало понятно что этого не сделать. Уже все ревлизовано как на примере @Sh4dow только на нативном js.

Answer (score 0):

```
tags2.outerHTML="<"+tag+">"+tag2.innerHTML+"</"+tag+">";
```

Comment: Только не `innerHTML`, а `textContent`.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать сам div редактируемым выставив ему contentEditable:

```js
document.getElementById('div').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  e.currentTarget.contentEditable = true
  e.currentTarget.focus()
})
```

```html
<div id=div>
  Some text <b>goes</b> here
</div>
```

Впрочем, не вижу никаких причин делать это по клику - можно просто прописать в разметке:

```html
<div contenteditable>
  Some text <b>goes</b> here
</div>
```